# Web form - bots getting past all checks when human cant.?

Tags: ajax, phpmailer

I have the following code, pretty standard - but it seems that the bots get by without even entering anything into the input fields! where as a normal person cannot since it checks upon submit, so I keep just getting empty emails.

Here is my code, if anyone has any ideas:

the javascript:

```
    $('form.ajax').on('submit', function () {
    if($(".field-b").val()) {
      return false;
    }
    var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
      var that  = $(this),
          name  = that.attr('name'),
          value = that.val();

      data[name] = value;
    });

    for(var property in data) {
      if(data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        if(data[property] == "") {
          $('[name="' + property + '"]').parent().addClass("error");
          return false;
        }
      }
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: type,
      data: data,
      success: function(response) {
        $(".info,.ajax").hide();
        $(".success-send").fadeIn(300);
        return false;
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The HTML:

```
<form class="ajax" action="../email.php" method="post"autocomplete="off">
          <div class="form-field">
            <input name="form_name" type="text" class="form-field-name">
            <label>Your Name</label>
            <div class="field-icon-name"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-field">
            <input name="form_business" type="text" class="form-field-business">
            <label>Business</label>
            <div class="field-icon-business"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-field">
            <input name="form_email" type="email" class="form-field-email">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <div class="field-icon-email"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-field">
            <input name="form_phone" type="text" class="form-field-phone">
            <label>Phone #</label>
            <div class="field-icon-phone"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-field special">
            <input name="form_b" type="text" class="form-field-b">
            <label>question</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-field">
            <textarea name="form_message"></textarea>
            <label>Message</label>
            <div class="field-icon-message"></div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
        </form>
```

And finally the PHP.

```
<?php

 session_start();

 $to = "myemail@domain.com";
 $name = $_POST['form_name'];
 $phone = $_POST['form_phone'];
 $email = $_POST['form_email'];
 $business = $_POST['form_business'];
 $email = $_POST['form_email'];
 $subject = 'Contact Form mattscorner';

 $message = 'Name:'.$name.'\n Email + phone:'.$email.", ".$phone."\n Business: ".$business."\n\n".$message;

 $headers = "From: $email\n";
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";

 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

 if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) echo "mail sent"; else echo "mail NOT sent";

?>
```

It's pretty standard code I think, but I just cant seem to get the bots to even get blocked by the field requirements.

I literally get emails that are just:

> Name:\n Email + phone:, Business:

Answer (score 0):

There's a fundamental misunderstanding here. Bots don't run JavaScript, so none of that matters, and you're not doing the same validations on the server side, so they have no trouble getting by. Implement your validations in PHP too.

Also, you really need to do more validation for security anyway - your script is open to all kinds of vulnerabilities, and you're building malformed, non-compliant messages.

I suggest you use an email library such as PHPMailer, which you tagged this question with.